# Nginx configuration sends all URLs to homepage

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

When using the configuration below, my webapp works as expected:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/frontend/web;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

However, when I try the configuration below, it does not work:

```
server {
    set $base_root /var/www/html;

    root $base_root;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root $base_root/frontend/web;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Now, all URLs simply take me back to the homepage.

Why? What am I missing here?

I need the second configuration to work because my webapp has a frontend and backend. And using rewrite rules with the first configuration has yielded no success.

Signed,
Beyond Frustrated

**Edit**
Including the .php block below:

```
location ~ \.(php|phar)(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.(?:php|phar))(/.*)$;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;

        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
```

Comment: Your example is missing the `location ~ \.php$` block, which is where the `index.php` is processed and is probably the `root` that is causing you problems.

Comment: I've added the block to the original question. This is what I've had in place. If there's something wrong, I'm not sure how to diagnose it.

Comment: So what's `/var/www/html` for? And does it include PHP files?

Comment: Yes, that is where my project files are. I'm using the Yii2-advanced template, which has a frontend and backend. `frontend/web` is for the frontend, `backend/web` is for the backend. I haven't included any blocks for the backend yet since I can't even get any pages on the frontend to load properly (besides the homepage). And if it matters at all, I'm launching this on AWS' Elastic Beanstalk.